# ¿Trigger in oracle after insert?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a netbeans web application using oracle database 11g, and i need to insert data on my table_B automatically after instert on my table_A,

my table_A has:

- id_product

del_product

contrat

pre_prod

and my table_B has the same columns but i need to copy all data from table_A after update.

i'm new using triggeres and i don't know anythoing about it, Could you help me?

this the code i try but it doesn't work.

```
   create or replace trigger color_omes
after update update of (id_del, dele, contr)
on dele
for each row
begin
insert into del3 values(new.id_del, new.dele, new.contr);
end color_omes;
```

but something went wrong, i get this error

```
ORA-00969: missing ON keyword
```

Comment: SO is not for tutorials and how-to. If you don't know triggers, you should first make some search, read some tutorials, study something and then try to write some code. If you have a problem with your code, feel free to post a question here.

Comment: i did a search and actually i have a code above, i've already written.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues in your code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER color_omes
AFTER UPDATE OF id_del, dele, contr
ON dele
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO del3 VALUES(:new.id_del, :new.dele, :new.contr);
END color_omes;
```

How it works:

```
SQL> select * from del3;

no rows selected

SQL> update dele set contr = 100;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from del3;

    ID_DEL       DELE      CONTR
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2        100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it runs but when i update data don't happen anything, the table is empty.

Comment: Add code, data samples, It makes much easier to find answers.

Comment: The trigger works, just showed what it does. If it really does what you expect, is of course a different question